# Flutter Put request, XMLHttpRequest Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The put request wasn't working until I made this modifications in flutter

1. flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp - Delete
2. flutterpackacges/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart - Modify "disable-extension" to "disable-web-security"

now the put request is working, but I can't understand why it wasn't working in the first place? can anyone explain this solution please.